# .htaccess and php includ on same server using subdomain

Tags: php

I have been searching all day for a solution to this and searched here.

I have a central file for including functions for all sites on the server, this looks up to the database and if valid includes the file as a .inc as the sites could be on any server so has to process over a url. So I set up a subdomain to test this and everything works fine, however if someone where to look up the link in the site they can go direct and browse the .inc file.

I've tried looking up on here how to deny someone from browsing the file if they are viewing through the browser. This works, however if the website requesting/including the functions.inc are hosted on the same server then the requesting HTTP_HOST/REFFERER becomes the subdomain and the functions.inc file is exluded.

So far I had this:-

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^http://(www.)?subdomainchecker.mysite.co.uk/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(inc)$ - [F]

See the subdomain acts like a service. And the reason I want to do this is that I want all the php functions in one place for everyone. that way I'm only maintaining one file. One bug fix etc.

Now I thought there has to be a way to check that there is a difference when using a subdomain.

However if there is a better way???

If this doesn't work maybe I could get htaccess to include (a virtual folder) to my subdomain folder so that I don't have to go over a url... but that wont work if the site gets hosted on another server?

Or... could I do a look up straight to the DB, as the user credentials only has SELECT privileges only. Could the DB contain all the functions and output them from a text field? Or have functions listings in a DB and retrieve the function when I do a database call?

Or... could I do a php XML request and return the php functions within an XML node?

I'd rather keep the functions and classes in a file than on a DB, but I am not sure how the best way to go about it is. All I want to do is keep my php functions in one place.

If anyone has any ideas?

Thanks

Andi

Comment: so wait, you are including a public file kept on a separate server?

Comment: or are all of the sites on the same server?

Comment: Well. I could be hosting sites or clients could be hosting their own. So wherever the websites are they have to include these (yes public functions and classes) but I don't want someone just browsing to them, copying the code and messing around with it, putting it back in the site locally. Otherwise defeats the whole purpose of keeping it all in one place. :o/

Answer (score 1):

Ok So I answered my own question eventually like so.

Step 1) I password protected my .inc files using .htaccess in the directory that stores my include files on my webservice (subdomain). Protecting both .inc and .php

```
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(inc|php|anyext)$">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "authenticate this puppy"
AuthUserFile /[servername]/[accountusernameOnServer]/.unseenfolder/public_html/[website_authentication_folder]/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

</FilesMatch>
```

This folder is now password protected by the encrypted .htpassword file outside my web root.

Step 2) Back in my now protected webserivce folder contains three files (one .php / two .inc files containing my functions and application file (session variables for the site)

1. **authenticate_some_websitesite_against_my_own_DB.php**
   This contains the account verification process (lookup to a database on my own server), note the host is always Localhost and I am using PHP PDO for convenience (just in case you have a Postgre database or MSSQL etc)
2. **application_for_site.inc**
   This contains/sets all the site session variables (user ID etc)
3. **a file without a name called .anyext** containing my global functions for all sites

Now here is the cool thing. THE PROCESS or how I got it to work.

1. I put my new website in a subfolder and include a file called authentication.php in my local folder in the site. I call this in the head of index.php in the site.
   This file contains my webkey, usernames and passwords to my clients table in my DB which is used to verify in the file I call from my subdomain... **authenticate_some_websitesite_against_my_own_DB.php**

I put all these variables in a url variable which also include my username and password to my protected subdomain.
So now it looks something like this: Of course I set the variables above

```
$link = "authenticate_anewsite.php";

// Create Website check link criteria.
$link .= "?website=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$link .= "&website_folder=$website_folder";
$link .= "&webkey=$webkey";
$link .= "&username=$username";
$link .= "&password=$password";
$link .= "&base_url=$base_url";
$link .= "&DBLangtype=$DBLangtype";
$link .= "&localDBtype=$localDBtype";
$link .= "&content_folder=$content_folder";
$link .= "&google_api=$google_api";
$link .= "&menu_folder=$menu_folder";
$link .= "&news_folder=$news_folder";
$link .= "&events_folder=$events_folder";
$link .= "&documents_folder=$documents_folder";
$link .= "&uploaded_images_folder=$uploaded_images_folder";
$link .= "&gallery_folder=$gallery_folder";


//// Do not delete required to access the link below
$PHP_AUTH_USER = "website_user"; /// Do NOT AMEND THIS
$PHP_AUTH_PW = "passw0rd"; /// Do NOT AMEND THIS
$path = "http://$PHP_AUTH_USER:$PHP_AUTH_PW@www.websitecheck.mydomain.com/"; /// Do NOT AMEND THIS LINK
$authCHK = $path . $link;

/// going to check that we connect
$handle = curl_init($authCHK);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

/// If server can't connect
if($httpCode == 401) {

    //set error handler
    set_error_handler("customError", E_ALL);

    /* Handle 404 here. */
    trigger_error("<strong style='color:red;'>Error: SERVER - $httpCode</strong> $website failed to connect to authenticate site.<br />Connection string..:\n $authCHK");

//  error_function(error_level,error_message,error_file,error_line,error_context) 

} else {

    require_once($authCHK);

} // end if

curl_close($handle);
```

Now the file successfully includes the .php file from the server because the username and password to it are parsed in the url.

in the **authenticate_anewsite.php** I just included (actually I did a require_once) this is the bit that authenticates my website against my clients table which runs these checks:

The MySQL database username and password are stored in this file. This account has only the priveliges of select.

- checks clients for existence of a webkey which I give them
- check the username against the clients table
- checks the password
- paid = true
- active = true

So the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients where paid=1 and active=1 and webkey = '$webkey' and username = '$username' and password = '$password'
```

If the required checks are verified then the num of records is 1, if this is >0 then my **authenticate_anewsite.php** includes the other two .inc files like this (the folder username and password have already been verified in the call.

if ($count_check > 0) {

```
$appliation = $path . 'application_for_my_site.inc';
$appliation = file_get_contents($appliation);
echo $appliation;

$functions = $path . '.anyext';
$functions = file_get_contents($functions);
echo $functions;

} else {
// redirect to the holding page
//header('Location: $base_url/500.shtml');
```

}

At this point its probably ok to set a session variable to not keep checking the database every time the index.php page is called from the actual site.

OK so this actually works although a little Archaic.

**The advantages of all this:**

- Functions and application are served from one file in a central location (one bug fix can fix all sites)
- Doesn't matter if the website is hosted on my server or on another
- A user cannot browse the files directly, because htaccess has password protected them
- Even if a user were to browse the subdomain/webservice in the browser by putting the link together with the folder username and password the browser, it doesn't server the PHP as is server sided script. It wont be able to see my username and database password, sql, or the name of the files I'm calling in by viewing source
- I have my functions in a file with no file name and an extension that I have made up this is the purpose of the .anyext (htaccess treats this the same and protects it, but because its an extension that I made up it makes it harder to guess, and generally invisible)
- indexes have been switched off so general browsing is not allowed on my webservice

OK so it took me two days to come up with this solution. I hope that my idea will help save someone a lot of time!

Bless You :o)

Andi Lee Davis